# Create temporary table inside a procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, procedure

Here is the error I get when I try to run the code below.

I spent a day on mySQL tutorials + forums without any success.

[image]

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_end_date_dwh_dimension_product;

delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_end_date_dwh_dimension_product()
BEGIN

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS __temp_BI__;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __temp_BI__
SELECT dp.sku, dp.start_date
FROM  dwh_dimension_product dp
ORDER BY dp.sku, dp.start_date;

DECLARE end_loop BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;

DECLARE sku1_ VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE sku2_ VARCHAR(50);   

DECLARE start_date1_ TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE start_date2_ TIMESTAMP;

DECLARE cursor_temp CURSOR
    FOR select * from __temp_BI__;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end_loop = FALSE; 

OPEN cursor_temp;

FETCH cursor_temp INTO sku1_, start_date1_;

while_label: WHILE (end_loop) DO

    IF end_loop = FALSE THEN
        LEAVE while_label;
    END IF;

    FETCH cursor_temp INTO sku2_, start_date2_;

    while_label2: WHILE (sku1_ = sku2_) DO
        UPDATE dwh_dimension_product dp1
        SET dp1.end_date = DATE_SUB(start_date2_, INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
        WHERE  dp1.sku = sku1_
        AND dp1.start_date = start_date1_;

        SET sku1_ = sku2_;
        SET start_date1_ = start_date2_;
        FETCH cursor_temp INTO sku2_, start_date2_;

        IF end_loop = FALSE THEN
            LEAVE while_label2;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    UPDATE dwh_dimension_product dp2
    SET dp2.end_date = NULL
    WHERE dp2.sku = sku1_
    AND dp2.start_date = start_date1_;

    SET sku1_ = sku2_;
    SET start_date1_ = start_date2_;
END WHILE;
CLOSE cursor_temp;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS __temp_BI__;
END $$  
delimiter ;
```

If I put this following code outside the procedure() it works

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS __temp_BI__;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __temp_BI__
SELECT dp.sku, dp.start_date
FROM  dwh_dimension_product dp
ORDER BY dp.sku, dp.start_date;
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __temp_BI__ AS SELECT ...`

Comment: [DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) is permitted only inside a [BEGIN ... END](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html) compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements. See [13.6.3 DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html).

Comment: @Mihai: add the "AS" statement doesn't change the error I get. Thx anyway.

Comment: @wchiquito I agree to what you said. All my DECLARE are contains in a BEGIN/END bloc. Thx for en-lighting me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Don't forget: `... and must be at its start, before any other statements.`.